# Como limitar o número geral de posts WordPress de dois loops diferentes

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá!

Tenho dois loops no meu index do WP, mas preciso de um número máximo de 3 posts no total. Se eu diminuir o número de posts por página para 3, ele vai alterar isso para CADA um dos loops, só que eu preciso limitar o número de posts TOTAL para 3.

Existe como fazer isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Você está usando a `WP_Query` pra gerar esses loops?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cada um dos *loops*, basta adicionar o parâmetro de paginação `posts_per_page`, para adicionar os 3 últimos *posts*. (Veja os parâmetros de paginação [aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)). Deste modo, você terá algo como

```
$query1 = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=3');
$query2 = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=3');
```

Se você quiser 3 *posts* **especificos**, você tem que fornecer os IDs deles

```
$query1 = new WP_Query('post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12 ));
```

Separe os objetos das *queries* em variáveis diferentes, assim a manipulação de ambos os *loops* fica mais simples.

**EDIT**

Confesso que me debati um pouco pra entender a sua pergunta, mas vamos lá. Você procura mostrar *apenas* 3 *posts*, vindos tanto da primeira quanto da segunda *query*. Invariavelmente, você vai ter que fazer duas consultas. O que pode te ajudar aqui são 2 propriedades que a classe *WP_Query* possuí: **`$post_count`** e **`$found_posts`** (Veja estas e outras propriedades da classe [aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties)). Veja um exemplo reduzido de como você pode arquitetar o seu código:

```
$args1 = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type' => 'post_type1'
);

$query1 = new WP_Query($args1);

$count = $query1->post_count;

if($count < 3) { //você tem 2, 1 ou 0 posts nessa consulta

    $args2 = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3 - $count, // a diferença
        'post_type' => 'post_type2'
    );

    $query2 = new WP_Query($args2);

    # ...
}
```

E, a partir desse ponto, você monta os seus *loops* com a presença (ou não) do objeto `$query2`.

Comment: Entendi. Na verdade assim já é como eu estou fazendo, porém precisava que, se tivesse 3 no primeiro, apareceria 0 no segundo; se tivesse 2 no primeiro, 1 no segundo; se tivesse 1 no primeiro, 2 no segundo e assim sucessivamente... Não tem como?

Comment: @Alceu sim. veja a resposta editada =)